# Copy row from one MySQL DB to another

Tags: mysql

How it's possible to copy one entry row of a table with same data to another (same ID, same data values) Database -> same table?

**Example:**

```
Table Units:
UID Department Name       Item 
67    HR       John Doe   Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both tables equal no. of columns and in same order you want to insert then just use below simple query-

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM units WHERE uid=67;
```

If you want to insert selected column in another table's selected columns and in your order then use below-

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2,col3,col4) SELECT uid,department,`name`,item FROM units WHERE uid=67;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO DB1.units SELECT * FROM DB2.units WHERE uid=67;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to copy some rows to table of another DB.

Try `INSERT SELECT Query`:

```
insert into db1.tbl(id,col1,col2)
select id,col1,col2 from db2.tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger option in mysql to make new table with same data.

Comment: Could you add more description (preferably steps/code) to aid your answer. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to copy table1 data to table2 with some condition.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ID, NAME) SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM table1 WHERE Col1='<Your_Condition>';
```

Here table2 have fields like ID and NAME and table1 have fields like Col1 and Col2.
In that case, above query copy table1 data to table2 on these fields where condition matched on table1, if you want to copy whole data of table1 then remove the `WHERE` condition from `Select` Query.